# Combination Lock Advice

Tags: java, locking, combinations

I am creating a Combination Lock class in Netbeans and I am confused as to why when I run the file I do not recieve any output. Anyone know what I am doing wrong? Any and all help wouldb e greatly appreciated! Here is the  code in my constructer class :

```
package combinationlock ;
/**
* A class to implement a combination lock with 26 dial positions
* and a three-letter combination
* 
* @Carlos
*/
public class CombinationLock
{
// instance variable declarations go here
private boolean open ;
private int Count ;
private String position1  ;
private String position2 ;
private String position3 ;
private String first = "F" ;
private String second = "I" ;
private String third = "U" ;


/**
 * Creates a lock with a given combination consisting of three upper-case characters.
 * @param first the first letter of the combination
 * @param second the second letter of the combination
 * @param third the third letter of the combination
 */
public CombinationLock(String first, String second, String third)
{ 
   this.first = first ;
   this.second = second ;
   this.third = third ;
   open = false ;
   Count = 0 ;
}


/**
 * Set the dial to a position
 * @param aPosition a String consisting of a single uppercase letter (A..Z)
 */
public void setPosition(String aPosition)
{   
    if (Count == 0)        
    {
       position1 = aPosition ;
       Count = Count + 1 ;
   }
   else if (Count == 1) 
   {
       position2 = aPosition ;
       Count = Count + 1 ;  
   }
   else if (Count == 2)
   {
       position3 = aPosition ;
   }
}

/**
 * Try opening the lock
 */
 public void tryToOpen()
 {
   if (first.equals(position1) && second.equals(position2) && third.equals(position3))
  {
     open = true ; 
     System.out.println("Its open!") ;
 }
 else
 {
     open = false ;
     System.out.println("Wrong combination! Please try again.") ;
 }
 }

/**
 * Check whether the lock is open
 * @return true or false indicating whether the lock is open
 */
 public boolean isOpen()
 {
   return open ;
 }

/**
 * Close the lock and print a message indicating that the lock is now closed
 */
 public void lock()
 {
     Count = 0 ;
     open = false ; 
     System.out.println("You re-apply the lock") ;
 }  
}
```

Here is the code I used in my tester class :

```
package combinationlock ;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane ; 
/**
 *
 * @author Carlos
 */
public class CombinationLockTester 
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    CombinationLock MasterLock = new CombinationLock("F", "I", "U");

    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
            ("Please enter first letter.") ;

    MasterLock.setPosition(input) ;

    String input2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
            ("Please enter second letter.") ;

    MasterLock.setPosition(input2) ;

    String input3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
            ("Please enter third letter") ;

    MasterLock.setPosition(input3);

    System.out.println("The combination entered was " +input + input2 +input3) ;
```

Comment: And what's the code you use to call this class?

Comment: What output are you expecting?  None of this code ever calls anything in the combinationlock class.

Comment: sorry, I added my tester class now. If that is what you required.

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Based on the code you have shown us, the problem is that your tester class does not try to either open or close the lock.  If that's not the real problem, show us all of your tester class.

I would also note that you are **violating accepted coding standards** for naming of identifiers.  A variable or field name should start with a lower-case letter.  Change `Count` to `count` and `MasterLock` to `masterLock`.